# Ubuntu Lost After Resizing its Partition

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I had a partition (sda11) which **Ubuntu 11.10** was installed on it.

I resized this partition from **34 GB** to **150 GB**.

Then I lost the GRUB menu.

I use the [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) application to fix it.

But now when I restart my PC, only **Microsoft Windows XP** will boot and the GRUB menu not shown.

I tried to use *grub-install*, *grub-update*, *grub*, *Bootable MBR Repair Softwares*, and ..., but nothing appened !

I try to install Ubuntu again on **sda11**, but the installer say : "Saving installed packages ..." 'til now !!

### How can I repair GRUB and recover my Ubuntu ???

Answer (score 3):

If you used gparted to resize the partition, it should've given you a warning - something along the lines "if you move the start of the partition, it will become un-bootable, you will need to do this and this to fix it."

You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and re-install GRUB using the [following instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)

I would advice you against using third-party "boot repair" applications.

Comment: check this other method http://askubuntu.com/questions/123099/not-able-to-create-boot-partition-in-grub-after-resizing-ubuntu-partition