# not able to create boot partition in grub after resizing ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, grub2, gparted

I booted from the live cd so that I could increase disk space and swap space of my ubuntu partition. Earlier I have windows partition as well but I deleted it and gave space to my ubuntu partition. When I booted after this I got the dreaded "no partition found" grub error. After some research I found out that I needed a boot partition in order to boot. However, now when I create a new partition (for boot), I can not manage "flags" on it. So, I'm not able to create a partition with "boot" flag. Please see the screenshot below.

What should I do? My intention was to set boot flag on the unallocatted space of 1.85 GB.[image]

Comment: On unallocatted space of 1.85 GB can you create a partition? And then make it bootable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i had the exact same problem at least 9-10 times each time i formatted my /home partition and the windows partition later.What i do every time is this:

1. mount the ubuntu live cd and try ubuntu
2. open terminal
3. sudo fdisk -l (that gives a list of partition)
4. sudo mount /dev/sdanumber_0f_disk_you_have_installed_the_ubuntu /mnt
   for example sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

lets say number_0f_disk_you_have_installed_the_ubuntu=X

1. sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/boot
2. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev/
3. sudo chroot /mnt
4. grub-install /dev/sda
5. sudo umount /mnt/dev
6. sudo umount /mnt
7. sudo reboot

Comment: If this happen again maybe its because either you are risizing the linux partition or you are formatting the windows partition and installing again windows.If the second happens you can format the windows and install and then format the ubuntu partition /root partition only and installing again linux---BUT after windows installation----That works for me!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a separate "boot partition" in order to boot Ubuntu - it was working just fine before, wasn't it?

What I suspect happened is that you moved the start of your Ubuntu partition which broke your bootloader. You need to reinstall GRUB, actually, `gparted` should've warned you.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php#faq-13

You may also need to set "boot" flag on `/dev/sda5`